# how to correctly map normal browser keyboard event into key code of page.event in phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs

I'm trying to record user keyboard event and replay it in [phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs)

The **client's page** (i.e. a firefox browser) code as below:

```
document.onkeydown=function(e){
    sendToPhantom( e.which)  //this will send browser key code to phantomjs
}
```

**in phantomjs**:

```
....
function keyFromClient(which){
    var c = which
    if (c==8) {
        c = page.event.key.Backspace //0x01000003 in Qt
    } else if (c==13) {
        c = page.event.key.Enter   //0x01000004 in Qt
    } else {
        c = String.fromCharCode(c)
    }
    page.sendEvent('keydown', c)
}
```

as you can see, it have to do a convertion from `e.which` to page.event.key for some special keys, like `BackSpace`, `Enter` etc., the [Qt::Key enum](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#Key-enum)

**Question**

How to correctly convert all e.which to page.event.key? There's so many possibilities, and it must be some standard ways to do this, any one knows?